# Prove that there are at most a countable amount of $x \in X$ with $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\mu(x) > 0$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space so that $\mu(X) < 
> \infty$ prove that there are at most a countable amount of $x \in X$ with $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\mu(\{x\}) > 0$.

So this question was asked on an exam I had yesterday and it seems so simple and intuitive, however I couldn't solve it. My first idea to just sum over all these measures and get an infinite measure instead of a finite one, but all theorems I've seen sum over a countable amount of elements.. 
Someone please enlighten me.

Comment: If uncountably many $x$ have positive measure, there is a positive integer $n$ so that $\mu(\{x\})$ exceeds $1/n$ for infinitely many $x$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that
$$M := \{x \in X : \mu(\{x\}) > 0 \}$$
is not countable and let
$$X_n := \{ x \in X : \mu(\{x\}) > \frac{1}{n} \}.$$
Then
$$M = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} X_n.$$

If $|X_n| < \infty$ for all $n$, then $M$ would be countable since the countable union of finite sets is again countable. Since we assumed $M$ to be not countable, it follows that there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $|X_n| = \infty$. Hence, we can take a countably infinite subset $A \subseteq X_n$ and get
$$\mu(X) \geq \mu(X_n) \geq \mu(A) = \sum_{x \in A} \mu(\{x\}) \geq \sum_{x \in A} \frac{1}{n} = \infty.$$
Since this is a contradiction to $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ being a finite measure space, our assumption must be false. Hence, $M$ can at most be countable.