# $\mu$ pure point measure if and only if $\mu(A)=\sum_{x\in A} \mu(\left\{x\right\})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$\mu$ is a pure point measure if and only if  for every $A\in \mathcal{B}(X)$, $\mathcal{B}(X)$ sigma-algebra Baire. $X$ compact hausdorff 
$\mu(A)=\sum_{x\in A} \mu(\left\{x\right\})$

I have this

If $\mu(A)=0$ is hold.

If $\mu(A)>0$, then exists $x\in A: \mu(\left\{x\right\})>0$
Then $\left\{x:\mu(A)>0\right\}=\bigcup_{x\in A} \left\{x:\mu(\left\{x\right\})>0\right\}$ and I do not know how to continue ...

Comment: See also: [Prove that there are at most a countable amount of $x \in X$ with $\{ x \} \in \mathcal{A}$ so that $\mu(x) > 0$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1650465)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think $\mu$ is supposed to be a finite measure. ''If" part: $\{x:\mu\{x\}>\frac 1 n\}$ is finite for each $n$ and hence $\{x:\mu\{x\}>0\}$ is an at most countable set , say $\{x_1,x_2,...\}$. Verify now that $\mu =\sum_n \mu\{x_n\}\delta_{x_n}$. (You need the fact that $\mu\{x\}=0$ if $x \notin \{x_1,x_2,...\}$). "Only if" part is obvious.

Comment: Presumably it would be sufficient for $\mu$ to be decomposable.

Comment: thanks. I have this.
Let $B=\left\{x\in A: \mu(\left\{x\right\})>0\right\}.$
In https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3001899/left-x-mu-left-x-right-0-right-is-countable 
$\left\{x:\mu(\left\{x\right\})>0\right\}$ is countable.

Now, $\mu(A)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\mu(B)=\mu(A\setminus B)+\sum_{x\in B} \mu(\left\{x\right\})$, and 
$A\setminus B=\left\{x\in A:\mu(\left\{x\right\})=0\right\}$
How prove $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$?

Comment: How prove $\mu(A\setminus B)=0$?
I have this.
Sup. $\mu(A\setminus B)>0$ then exists $x\in A\setminus B$ such that $\mu(\left\{x\right\})>0$ a contradiction. It is correct?

Comment: @eraldcoil Yes, that is correct.