# Let $(X,\sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space $\sigma$ is $σ-$finite Borel measure of$\mathbb{R}$.Denote$E:=\{x : \mu(\{x\})>0\}$. Prove $E$ is countable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\sigma,\mu)$ be a measure space such that  $\sigma$ is $σ-$finite Borel measure of $\mathbb{R}$.

Denote $E:=\{x : \mu(\{x\})>0\}$.

Prove $E$ is countable.

My attempt :

Let $E$ be an uncountable set.

$\mu(X)=\mu(E)=\mu(\bigcup\{x\})=\bigcup(\mu\{x\})$.

I am trying to prove that since $E$ is not countable there is no partition of  $G_1,G_2,\cdots$ such that $\mu(G_i)<\infty$ when $\{G_i\}$ are countable.

Since  $\sigma$ is $σ-$finite$ there is a contradiction.

Is my idea correct ?

Comment: This is surely a duplicate.

Comment: I found this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650465/prove-that-there-are-at-most-a-countable-amount-of-x-in-x-with-x-in?noredirect=1&lq=1 but this is not a duplicate since this is not a finite measure space.

Comment: It does follow since a countable union of countable sets is still countable. Given a countable collection $\{ G_i \}_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ of sets of finite measure, such that $\sqcup G_i =X$, define $E_i:=E\cap G_i$.

Comment: You wrote:  "$\sigma$ is $σ-$finite Borel measure of $\mathbb{R}$".  Do you mean $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite Borel measure of $\mathbb{R}$? So $X = \Bbb R$?

Comment: @Ramiro yes indeed

Comment: If $E$ be an uncountable set, you cannot write $\mu(\bigcup_{x \in E}\{x\})=\bigcup_{x \in E}(\mu\{x\})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a general one.

> Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, such that for all $x \in X$, $\{x\} \in \Sigma$.  Then the set $\{x \in X : \mu(\{x\})>0\}$ is countable.

**Proof**: Let $E=\{x \in X : \mu(\{x\})>0\}$ and for each $n \in \Bbb N$, $n>1$, let $E_n =\{x \in X : \mu(\{x\})>\frac{1}{n}\}$. Clearly, $E=\bigcup_n E_n$.

Now, since $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space, there is a sequence $\{X_i\}_{i}$ of sets in $\Sigma$ such that, for  all $i$, $\mu(X_i) <+\infty$ and $X = \bigcup_i X_i$. So, for each $i$ and each $n$, $X_i \cap E_n$ is a finite set.

So we have
$ E= X \cap E = \bigcup_i \bigcup_n (X_i \cap E_n)$. That means $E$ is a countable union of finite sets. So $E$ is (at most) countable.

Comment: Thanks , the given $X=\mathbb R$ is necessary ?

Comment: @Algo , No. The result is in fact a general result. All you need is $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ to be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, and the condition that, for all $x \in X$, $\{x\} \in \Sigma$.